# ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to ignore all urls in my site that start with /blog/...

I have /blog ignored with

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("blog/{*path}");
```

but this doesn't seem to be ignoring urls suchs as /blog/feed/rss

EDIT:

I left out that this is the very first item in RegisterRoutes method. No routes are being registered before it.

Comment: What do you have after or before that? Remember, order matters when defining routes.

Comment: What happens when you visit `/blog/feed/rss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use httpHandlers in your web.config to achieve this effect at a higher level.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="blog/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

But besides that, your route should work. I don't see any reason it would not unless it was pre-empted by another route (this could happen if you are using AreaRegistration).

Comment: i dont even remember what i was doing when i asked this question, but what you seem to respond with would work. thanks.